# Site.com Studio Web to case Form

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, web2case

I am creating Site.com Studio form, where I have selected 2 picklist ( one is dependent on other) which is working fine in Case object record.

But when I create form in site.com studio where I add these picklist fields, controlling of picklist values doesnot happen.
UI shows correct picklist values:
[image]

Site.com Studio Preview below which shows all the option in "Purpose" field.
[image]

Can you please help how can we achieve that on Site.com studio.